# From the SCCM client system, can you list the deployment(s) currently associated to a missing patches?

Tags: powershell, deployment, wmi, patch, sccm

I'm attempting to build a PowerShell module to help diagnose SCCM issues without giving the system admins access to the SCCM console.  The code below currently finds all missing patches on a system but i want to be able to organize them:

> 1. Organize patches by deployment name
> 2. Display the deployment install deadline
> 3. List the Patches missing

Code that gets all missing patches:

```
$Results = (get-wmiobject -ComputerName $env:ComputerName -query "SELECT * FROM CCM_UpdateStatus" -namespace "root\ccm\SoftwareUpdates\UpdatesStore" | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Missing"})
```

Output Snippet:

```
__GENUS                  : 2
__CLASS                  : CCM_UpdateStatus
__SUPERCLASS             :
__DYNASTY                : CCM_UpdateStatus
__RELPATH                : CCM_UpdateStatus.UniqueId="4ffd2339-7fa5-4716-b64e-78e3dce16d59"
__PROPERTY_COUNT         : 15
__DERIVATION             : {}
__SERVER                 : ……………………………… 
__NAMESPACE              : ROOT\ccm\SoftwareUpdates\UpdatesStore
__PATH                   : \\………………………………\ROOT\ccm\SoftwareUpdates\UpdatesStore:CCM_UpdateStatus.UniqueId="4ffd2339-7fa5-4716-b64e-78e3dce16d59"
Article                  : 3178662
Bulletin                 :
ExcludeForStateReporting : False
Language                 :
ProductID                : e6cf1350-c01b-414d-a61f-263d14d133b4
RevisionNumber           : 200
ScanTime                 : 20180320184935.000000+000
Sources                  : {{7D052A75-2032-4F02-BAC9-9EDA4DBD58DE}}
SourceType               : 2
SourceUniqueId           : {7D052A75-2032-4F02-BAC9-9EDA4DBD58DE}
SourceVersion            : 68
Status                   : Missing
Title                    : Update for Microsoft Office 2016 (KB3178662) 32-Bit Edition
UniqueId                 : 4ffd2339-7fa5-4716-b64e-78e3dce16d59
UpdateClassification     : e6cf1350-c01b-414d-a61f-263d14d133b4
PSComputerName           : WGC1107B87PH2
```

I cannot determine how to get a patches associated deployment name or that patches install deployment deadline.  Once I can get those two associations I would like to have output something like below:

```
Baseline Patch Deployment:
Install Deadline:  Apr 12, 2018
Missing Patches:
Patch1
Patch2
Patch3

Office 2016 April Patch Deployment:
Install Deadline:  Apr 27, 2018
Missing Patches:
Patch1
Patch2
Patch3

Missing but Unapproved Patches:
Install Deadline: None
Missing Patches
Patch1
Patch2
Patch3
```

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it can be done. I don't have the time to look right now but all the info is there in WMI. It just takes a bit of effort to find the right classes and link things together sometimes. I will look tonight if I have time.

Comment: If you do find the correct WMI info, would you please link me the website(s) where you got it?  I've looked myself but with little understanding of what I was searching for.  I want to also build some support for this module so others can add functionality to it in the future if needed and the links would be a great benifit. @EBGreen

Comment: Oh, there isn't a website that I have ever found I just sit down with [WMI Explorer](https://github.com/vinaypamnani/wmie2/releases) and start poking around in classes until I find what I need. :)